# Workflow service as a service reference on WCF service

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I have added workflow service as reference to wcf service, and it created web.config file with client endpoint. while creating the proxy object its running into issue. Its not able to recognize the contract and throwing below error -

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'servicerefname.interfacename' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I checked reference.cs file and config, everything looks fine. Can someone post redirect me to example where workflow service been reference from WCF?

Note - Its in .Net 4.0

Comment: I think you mean you added it as a service reference.

Comment: yes thats correct its service reference.

Comment: Are you calling a WF service from WCF service ? Calling service from a service ?

Comment: yes. calling service from service.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the web.config in the calling project. 
For example if you added a service refernce to a project called: MyGateway.proj. and then you have a website that uses classes in the MayGatway.proj. If it is the wbesite that calls the Gateway, which in turn calls the webservice - It is important that the web.config settings are applied in the website.